# Cannot add CircularReveal library by ozodrukh in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0 and am trying to add [CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) library .I have followed the instructions mentioned there.

my `build.gradle(Module: app)` is :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.geronimo.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:(latest-release)@aar'
    }

I have added the repository in `build.gradle(Project: MyApplication3)`

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is

```
 D:\Workspaces\AndroidStudio\Studio1.0\MyApplication3\app\build.gradle
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:(latest-release)
    <a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I have tried variations of the dependency too ie:

```
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:(latest-release)@aar' 
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:(v1.0.4)@aar' 
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal-v1.0.4 @aar'
```

The error always remains as `Failed to resolve...`

Is there any other way to import a remote aar file and to add this dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `@aar` file to the `libs` directory manually. Then by going to

`Files>Project Structure>Dependency`

on the *right red cross* choose `library dependency`. This will prompt you a dialog where you can search for your dependency and add them.

or

download [circularReveal library](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) *from github* and import it as `Module Dependency` from `Files>Project Structure>Dependency`

Comment: This isn't a maven cetral library.Its repo is in [jitpack](https://www.jitpack.io/#ozodrukh/CircularReveal/1.0.4)

Comment: Have you tried downloading `@aar` files and manually copying them to your project?

Comment: ok than download [circularReveal library from github](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) and import it as `Module Dependency` from `Files>Project Structure>Dependency`

Comment: Actually manually adding the aar solved it.There is a spelling mistake in the aar name that I overlooked its `circual` and not `circular`.Just add the aar into your answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: @Droidekas actually i have added that also in the answer. However i am editing it with further information maybe it will help someone else with similar problem. Glad that you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to put only version number without brackets and 'v' char
`com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.0.4@aar`

Comment: ok, you have also to include

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. After I checked, I saw that the problem was the miniSDKversion which was lower than 15. Once I changed it to 15, it worked.

minSdkVersion 14 (change it to 15 or above)
        targetSdkVersion 26

Then paste this to your library dependency

`implementation ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }`

Also add remote maven url

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```